# Undefined symbols "_TLSv1_1_client_method" for x86_64 when compiling httpd on Mac os 10.8

Tags: macos, apache, compilation, clang

The detail error message is below.

```
$ ./configure
$ make
```

then ...

```
/usr/share/apr-1/build-1/libtool --silent --mode=link /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.8.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc     -lssl -lcrypto -lpthread  \
         -o ab  ab.lo      -L/usr/lib -R/usr/lib -laprutil-1 -lexpat -liconv -lsqlite3 -lldap -llber -llber -L/usr/lib -R/usr/lib -lapr-1 -lpthread 

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

"_TLSv1_1_client_method", referenced from:
_main in ab.o
"_TLSv1_2_client_method", referenced from:
_main in ab.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Please provide the link command ;-)

Comment: Added the libtool command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

APR and apr-util are required dependencies.

So - before building httpd on Mac,

port install APR

port install apr-util

Solved this.

Comment: I've just installed apr and apr-util but this hasn't solved the error. Maybe because I've installed them with brew?

Comment: need more detailed info of the error. it is possible that after the brew installation, the path is not set to including APR and utils.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, you might have to set the 'OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR' variable to '/opt/local'.
You can do that by giving '-DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=/opt/local' as command line argument when executing cmake.